# Unable to load the UIImageView and UILabel immediately with the data from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a view controller called ProfileViewController and it contains a UIImageView for displaying the user avatar and a UILabel for displaying the username. However, it takes a while to show the avatar and username. If I go to other view controller and reopen it again, it actually can show them immediately. Also, I have tried to print out the username and avatar url and I can receive the value from Firebase instantly as well.

Here is the code:

```
func setUp(){

    //load avatar and other informations
    databaseRef.child("profiles").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("information").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.username.text = value?["username"] as? String

        if let avatarURL = value?["avatar"] as? String {

            if let url = URL(string: avatarURL){
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){
                    (data, response, error) in
                    if let data = data{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.avatar.image = UIImage(data: data)
                        }
                    }
                }
                task.resume()
            }
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. 
1. Use different images and qualities for easy loading. E.g lesser size and quality for thumbnail.
2. Implement an image cache so that you don't need to worry about the next download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to optimize this , as you have nested needed asynchronous calls , what you can change is to use  [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) to cache the image for upcoming visits to that vc